# Canonical Hostname with URLRewrite 2.0 behind load balancer

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, load-balancing

I have two IIS7 web servers behind a load-balancer. The URL Rewrite 2.0 module is installed on both servers and the following rewrite rule applied to both instances:

```
<rule name="Enforce canonical hostname" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

When I try to navigate to http://mydomain.com, my web browser hangs indefinitely. I suspect the load-balancer is affecting the way URL Rewrite works, but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up using the following technique:

http://www.mcanerin.com/en/articles/301-redirect-iis.asp

The key was to add the **$S$Q** to the end of the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is , 
1. load balancer forwards your request to your child servers 
2. and when request comes to child servers they redirect the request according to your URL redirect rule, so your request is redirected and again comes on Load balancer 
3. and the same procedure(step 1-2) is followed,

thus your request loops again and again and your browser gets hanged.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Sumit. Regarding the loop... wouldn't my rule not apply on the second iteration of the loop since I'm redirecting to www.mydomain.com. My rule should only apply to mydomain.com without the www.

Comment: I think it would redirect till you provide full path, that is the path till your page..even is you provide www. , i think it would redirect..though I am not sure of it..but i think thats the concept behind redirection , would suggest you to try out once on your server. by removing the redirection rule or entering the full path of the page which you want to access and see whats happening.